# Mixing childs with cdata under the same node. Is it valid?

Tags: php, xml, simplexml, cdata

I need to parse the following xml document (which is coming from external web service):

```
...
<dati>
    <Riconoscimento>
        <IdentificativoPosizione>xxxx</IdentificativoPosizione>
        <OutputRestituiti>xxx</OutputRestituiti>
    </Riconoscimento>
    <![CDATA[text text text]]>
</dati>    
...
```

The problem is that until there is node "Riconoscimento" simplexml parser fails to read cdata section, if i remove that child, everything is working without problems.

So the main question is: is it a valid xml document, and if it's valid is there some way to access CDATA section with php without manually removing extra childs?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can get it like this:

```
$x = simplexml_load_string('<root><dati>
    <Riconoscimento>
        <IdentificativoPosizione>xxxx</IdentificativoPosizione>
        <OutputRestituiti>xxx</OutputRestituiti>
    </Riconoscimento>
    <![CDATA[text text text]]>
</dati></root>', 'SimpleXMLElement', LIBXML_NOCDATA);

var_dump((string)$x->dati);
```

Note the `LIBXML_NOCDATA` parameter to convert the CDATA to a text node.

Comment: Thanks, i was missing "(string)" casting (it wasn't visible in debugger without explicit cast)

Answer (score 1):

First of all: this is a valid XML document (see [here](http://www.w3.org/TR/2008/REC-xml-20081126/#sec-cdata-sect)).

> Definition: **CDATA sections** may occur
>   anywhere character data may occur;
>   they are used to escape blocks of text
>   containing characters which would
>   otherwise be recognized as markup.
>   CDATA sections begin with the string "
>   `<![CDATA[` " and end with the string "
>   `]]>` ":

In your case the `<data/>`-element is a mixed-content element.

```
$xmlString = <<<XML
<dati>
    <Riconoscimento>
        <IdentificativoPosizione>xxxx</IdentificativoPosizione>
        <OutputRestituiti>xxx</OutputRestituiti>
    </Riconoscimento>
    <![CDATA[text text text]]>
</dati>
XML;
$xml = simplexml_load_string($xmlString);
var_dump((string)$xml);

/*
 * outputs:
 * string(37) "
 *
 *        text text text
 *    "
 */
```

(there is no need to pass `LIBXML_NOCDATA`)

Comment: I think he means he wants to output both the xml elements (`<Riconoscimento>`) and the text enclosed in `<!CDATA[` no?